# wordpress wpdb->update strange error by converting single quote to html entity

Tags: wordpress

**Update Julu 2018:**

I find out problem is something else. The print error method will always print out a encoded html message like the one below. If the message is not showing any extra piece of information means the SQL query is fine.

---

**Original Question:**

I tried to update the invite_code by using the $wpdb->update method, but it return strange error, it seems like WordPress convert the single quote to html entity - &#39

Please help me if anyone knows why it will convert the single quote to HTML entity automatically.

I am not able to do use any WordPress built-in method to update the query because the problem seems to happen at the prepared statement which will use in every built-in method.

> **WordPress database error: UPDATE exhibitor_invite SET invite_code =
>    &#039 ;8j8mxfkkubd0kppi082p&#039 ; WHERE id = 10**

```
     function createCode() {
        $length = 20;
        $inviteCode = "";
        $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
            $inviteCode .= $characters[mt_rand(0, strlen($characters))];
        }
        return $inviteCode;
     }

     function updateCode($id) {
            global $wpdb;
            $wpdb->show_errors();
            $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
            $invite_code =  createCode() ;

            // I tried to esc the string, but it doesn't work
            // $invite_code = $wpdb->esc_like($invite_code);

            // I also tried to use normal query, but it return the same error
            // $affected_rows =  $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
            //  " UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}exhibitor_invite SET invite_code = %s WHERE id = %d", $invite_code, $id ));

            $affected_rows = $wpdb->update( $prefix.'exhibitor_invite', 
                array('invite_code' => $invite_code),
                array('id' => $id), 
                '%s', 
                '%d' );
            $wpdb->print_error();
            if(!is_bool($affected_rows)) {
                return $affected_rows  > 0;
            }
            return $affected_rows;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps way too late, but in case not I had the exact same problem and spent hours looking for a solution.

It seems that the WordPress property 'update' of wpdb object is where the problem occurs.
One solution that I found to work is to store the entire SQL string in a variable and then before using it, pass the variable through a PHP function of [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

PHP manual states:

> This function is used to create a legal SQL string that you can use in an SQL statement. The given string is encoded to an escaped SQL string, taking into account the current character set of the connection.

Your solution may look something like this (untested).

```
$sql_string = 
 "
 UPDATE ${prefix}exhibitor_invite
 SET invite_code = %s
 WHERE id = %d
 ";

//procedural style
mysqli_real_escape_string( $your_conn_to_server, $sql_string );

//update
$wpdb->update( $wpdb->prepare(
  $sql_string,
  array(
     $invite_code,
     $id
  )
), OBJECT );
```

Comment: Hi. I find out problem is something else. The print error method will always print out a encoded html message which is what I wrote above. If the message is not showing any extra piece of information means the SQL query is fine.